# How to simulate random variates with no pdf in R?

Tags: r

I want to simulate a string of random non-negative integer values in R.

However, those values should not follow any particular probability distribution function and could be empirically distributed.

How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a distribution; there is no alternative, philosophically. There's no such thing as a "random number," only numbers randomly distributed according to some distribution.

To sample from an empirical distribution stored as `my_dist`, you can use `sample()`:

```
my_dist <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55)   # first 10 Fibonacci numbers
sample(my_dist, 100, replace = T)                # draw 100 numbers from my_dist w/ replacement
```

Or, for some uniformly-distributed numbers between (for instance) 1 and 10, you could do:

```
sample(1:10, 100, replace = T)
```

There are, of course, specific distributions implemented as functions in `base` R and various packages, but I'll avoid those since you said you weren't interested in them.

---

Editing per Rui's good suggestion: If you want non-uniform variables, you can specify the `prob` parameter:

```
sample(1:3, 100, replace = T, prob = c(6, 3, 1))
  # draws a 1 with 60% prob., a 2 with 30% prob., and a 3 with 10% prob.
```

Comment: Upvote but maybe you could also include an example of using argument `prob`, for instance, `sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = my_dist)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas And imply a distribution? Perish the thought! :) Great suggestion; I've incorprated it.